# Python convert array of Jsons to Excell file within a single loop

Tags: python, json, pandas, xlsx

I am currently trying to convert many Arrays of Jsons, with a single loop, to an Excell file, using pandas.

Input:
[json 1,json 2, json 3]
[json 4, json 5, json 5]
etc.

code:

```
for t in liste:
   response = client.list_discovered_resources(
      resourceType=t,
      limit=0,
      includeDeletedResources=False,
    
         )
   if response['resourceIdentifiers']:    
       print('\n ******************** Resources of Type ',t,'\n')
       print(jsbeautifier.beautify(str(response['resourceIdentifiers']))) 

# at this point, we have gotten many arrays of jsons displayed in the output.
       pd.DataFrame(response['resourceIdentifiers']).to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

as you can see, each ****response['resourceIdentifiers']****represents an array of jsons. When I run this loop, I only get the last array of jsons ( producde in the last loop iteration ) displayed in the Excell file.

I want, to have the arrays displayed in the same file.

can someone help me with this issue ?
Thank you so much in advane

Comment: Is response['resourceIdentifiers'] a json or a list of json?

Comment: response['resourceIdentifiers'] is an array of jsons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
list_of_dfs =  []
for t in liste:
    response = client.list_discovered_resources(
        resourceType=t,
        limit=0,
        includeDeletedResources=False,

    )
    if response['resourceIdentifiers']:
        print('\n ******************** Resources of Type ', t, '\n')
        print(jsbeautifier.beautify(str(response['resourceIdentifiers'])))

        list_of_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(response['resourceIdentifiers']))

final_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, ignore_index=True).to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Use this if you want to save each dataframe in separate sheet.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')

for index, t in enumerate(liste):
    response = client.list_discovered_resources(
        resourceType=t,
        limit=0,
        includeDeletedResources=False,

    )
    if response['resourceIdentifiers']:
        print('\n ******************** Resources of Type ', t, '\n')
        print(jsbeautifier.beautify(str(response['resourceIdentifiers'])))

        df = pd.DataFrame(response['resourceIdentifiers'])
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'df_{index}', startrow=0, startcol=0, index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works very well. 
BTW, is it possible to put every response['resourceIdentifiers'] in a single sheet ? meaning having an excell document, with a sheet displaying the result of each iteration.
It would be awesome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the Excel file.
Try to first take all jsons and put them into one pandas.DataFrame and then save this one DataFrame into Excel

Comment: I know that. I tried to put them all in a file and convert it. but pandas.dataframe seems not to accept a file composed of many arrays of Json.
Do you know a possibility to only save the Jsons ? ( I mean without the arrays )

Comment: See comment from Muhammad hassan. This is exactly what I meant with my answer, but he included the code.